# coc.nvim no funciona el automcompletado

Tags: nvim

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi problema es que al instalar  - neoclide/coc en mi packer.lua , me funciona el cuadro de autocompletacion , pero no me deja selecionar las sugerencias del autocompletado , como pueden ver en la imagen , en la flecha de color roja , no me deja selecionarlo , precio en ter o tab y nada , solo se queda en blanco

Answer (score 0):

En el repositorio del plugin te indica que debes agregar estas líneas en tu .vimrc:

```bash
" Seleccionar la sugestión con el tabulador
inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
      \ coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#next(1) :
      \ CheckBackspace() ? "\<Tab>" :
      \ coc#refresh()
inoremap <expr><S-TAB> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#prev(1) : "\<C-h>"

" Seleccionar la sugestión con enter.
inoremap <silent><expr> <CR> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm()
                              \: "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"
```

Espero que todavía te sirva de ayuda y sigas utilizando Vim. Saludos crack!